# error:Execution failed for task ':app:kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin'

Tags: android, kotlin, plugins, build.gradle, kapt

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/66LzE.png)

The above error is shown when running a project which uses kapt in android studio. Can someone tell how to rectify it?

I have used kapt plugin for the project and there are some errors in gradle.
This is my build.gradle(app):

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.studentregister'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.studentregister"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {
    def room_version = "2.5.2"
    def lifecycle_version = "2.6.1"

    // ViewModel
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$lifecycle_version")
    // LiveData
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:$lifecycle_version")

    //room
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:$room_version"
    //coroutines
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.7.1")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.7.1")

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.8.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
}
```

Comment: Can you copy and paste the error message from the image here? The whole message is not visible.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Execution failed for task ':app:kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76025260/21590355)